# How to get data inside a component after it is available through graphql in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I have a parent component which runs a query:

```
export const GET_VESSEL = gql`
  query vesselById($id: ID!) {
    vesselById(id: $id) {
      flagName
      flagCode
    }
  }
`;
```

After this I have the error, loading and then data:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_VESSEL,
    {
      variables: {
        id: props.vesselId
      }
    }
  );

  if (loading) return <div style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>Loading...</div>
  if (error) return <div style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>Error loading data</div>

  const vesselData = data.vesselById;
```

From here I have this in my return:

```
return (
    <SubHeader data={vesselData} />
  );
```

The problem I am having is my child component `<SubHeader />` has props which return `undefined` and then the props come in after the initial render. Since the child component renders before the data has arrived, I get undefined as props so it does not load my child component props inside it. What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: You may need to update the component when your props are updated. If you are using react < 16.8, have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate. If you are using 16.8 or greater: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html. Without seeing more code, it's hard to determine how `<Subheader>` is being used

Comment: `data` will be defined at the same time (within the same render) as your `loading` variable changes from `true` to `false`. If you are not rendering `SubHeader` until `loading` is false as shown in the code below, the `data` you pass to `SubHeader` will always reflect your completed request. It sounds like there's something else going on with your code.